# Using strtok to store a simple equation into an array and then perform the operation?

Tags: c

I am trying to use `strtok` to break a simple equation like `5 + 4` down and store each part into an array, and once I have done this, perform the operation indicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include "stdafx.h"

int main() {
    char uin[10], op[10], error = 'e';
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = " ";
    double num1, num2, fNum1, res;
    int i = 0;
    int x, y, z, a, b, c, op1;

    printf("Welcome to the calculator, please enter an equation\n");

    while (error == 'e') { // & assigns address and * gives access to what it points to
        a = &uin[0];
        b = &uin[2];
        c = &uin[4];

        gets(uin);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("Is this what you entered? %s\n", uin);
        token = strtok(uin, s);
        //x = &token;
        //printf("The element in the array currently assigned to token is: %s\n", token);

        while (token != NULL) {
            if (isdigit(token[0])) {
                num1 = atof(token);
                printf("token is now: %1.2f\n", num1);
            } else
                strcpy(op, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            if (isdigit(token[0])) {
                num1 = atof(token);
            } else
                strcpy(op, token);

            //token = strtok(NULL, s);
            //y = &token;
            //printf("The element in the array currently assigned to token is: %s\n", token);
        }

        //token = strtok(NULL, s);
        //y = &token;
        //printf("The element in the array currently assigned to token is: %s\n", token);

        //token = strtok(NULL, s);
        //z = &token;
        //printf("The element in the array currently assigned to token is: %s\n", token);

    }

    system("pause");
}
```

I am really having a hard time with this. I think that I am using `strtok` correctly to take the first part of the `gets(uin)` and storing it, but I don't understand how to take the middle part (`+` `-` `*` or `/`) and store it.

Comment: In K&R book, they write a calculator (reverse polish). They just use `getchar`. That way you can test all the input as it come in. If it's a digit, or one of the symbols to do a calculation. They use switches to test for `+, -, *, /, **`.  `getchar` give you very good control over everything.

Comment: When i tried compiling your code, a got a lot of warnings. `test.c:19:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         a = &uin[0];`   A bunch of those, and also `test.c:(.text+0x54): warning: the gets function is dangerous and should not be used.` Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Using `gets();` is now a *"Hanging-Offense"*, use `fgets` instead and throw away whatever reference suggested using `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is not the proper tool for your purpose. `strtok` modifies the string, overwriting the separator. It would only work for expressions where all tokens are separated by spaces, an unnecessary and counterintuitive constraint. For a more effective approach, either use a pointer and explicit tests for each character or use non intrusive parsing helpers such as `strspn()`, `strcspn()` and `strtold()`.

Furthermore, you should not use `gets()`, this function is obsolete and was removed from the latest version of the C Standard. It cannot be used safely: any sufficiently large input will corrupt your program and have undefined behavior. Use `fgets()` instead to read a full line into a sufficiently large array: 10 bytes is definitely too small. `rewind()` is also unnecessary.